# how to map from a domain model to a view model from MVC controller with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I am trying to figure out how AutoMapper works in creating a map from the domain model to the view model with a complex collection. 
Within my domain model (Search.Domain) ,

I have the following:

```
namespace Search.Domain.Model
{
    public class Result
    {
        public int SearchTime { get; set; }
        public List<ResultDetails> Context { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultDetails
    {
        public string Entity { get; set; }
        public string Jurisdiction { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
        public string AssociatedLink { get; set; }
        public int Relevance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

with the MVC project (Search.WebUI) I have the following:

```
namespace Search.WebUI.Models
{
    public class ResultViewModel
    {
        public int SearchTime { get; set; }
        public List<ResultDetails> Context { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultDetails
    {
        public string Entity { get; set; }
        public string Jurisdiction { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
        public string AssociatedLink { get; set; }
        public int Relevance { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Within the controller (HomeController.cs)

```
namespace Search.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ISearchResultManager sr = new ResultManager();  

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ResultViewModel searchresults;

            var results = sr.GetSearchResults(5);
            Mapper.CreateMap<Search.Domain.Model.Result, ResultViewModel>();

            searchresults = Mapper.Map<Search.Domain.Model.Result, ResultViewModel>(results);

            return View("Home", searchresults);
        }
    }
}
```

The error message that is being generated when run is:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
ResultDetails -> ResultDetails
Search.Domain.Model.ResultDetails -> Search.WebUI.Models.ResultDetails

Destination path:
ResultViewModel.Context.Context.Context0[0]

Source value:
Search.Domain.Model.ResultDetails
```

In looking at this it appears that the nested `List<ResultDetails>` is causing an issue but I don't know what I am supposed to do to handle this type of mapping.

Is it correct to go all the way back into the domain for reference to the type? This seems as if I am pulling the domain into the UI which I would not want to do?

Is there another option for mapping domain models to view models in the UI? Basically I was hoping to have a view model within the UI that I could extend beyond the domain model for UI purposes and not put a reference to the domain model.

I am new to `autoMapper` so this entire thing may be wrong? I would appreciate any suggestions or guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoMapper doesn't look at all potential child mapping when mapping a containing class. You need to explicitly add a mapping for the `ResultDetails` as well:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Search.Domain.Model.Result.ResultDetails,
                         Search.WebUI.Models.ResultDetails>();
```

Comment: One other note - you only need to do CreateMap once per AppDomain, so put that CreateMap code in Global.asax or similar.